# Cassandra Conditional Update combined with IF EXISTS

Tags: cassandra, cql, conditional-operator

I know that it's possible to use conditional updates (lightweight transaction) in cassandra.

```
update myTable 
set 
col1 = 'abc',
where id = 1 
IF priority < 2
```

This allows me to update only rows with a higher priority. Unfortunately when the row does not exists the statement returns false. Is it possible to combine "IF NOT EXISTS" and "IF" with an OR operation?

Otherwise i have to execute more queries to the cluster. In my use case this could be a big performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - unfortunately it's not possible in cassandra. We have to separate the insert and update statement.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8335

```
insert ... if not exists
update ... if priority < 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IN operator, assuming that "priority" has a finite (and possibly small) allowed set of values, such as 0 and 1. By adding the NULL value to the set, the query will succeed also if the row does not exist.

You're using a single query, but note that the performance implications are non-negligible, and could be the same or worse than using two.

```
update myTable 
set 
col1 = 'abc',
where id = 1 
IF priority IN (0, 1, NULL)
```

Comment: I have found that (at least in driver v3.17.0) this works fine as a SimpleStatement, but it doesn't work with prepared statements. For TEXT columns at least, IF col1='' is treated differently to IF col1=null, but None and '' are both serialized to the same byte sequence when the tuple parameter is bound to the prepared statement.